# Proof that these rotation moves can explore the whole binary tree search space

Tags: tree, theory, proof, formal-verification

I am working on this project where I am required to find the theoretical proof for following.

I have a particular type of binary trees, where

1) each internal node will definitely have two children.

2) There are n leaf nodes and can be assumed in order 1 to n from left most to right most.

Now this is clear that there would be exponential number of such possible trees which have theses two properties.

If I start from any random tree and randomly sample one of the internal node perform one of the two operations Left Rotate or Right Rotate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation), randomly. Is it possible to start from any random to tree to any other tree in the search space.

I have tried various resources but couldn't find any proof for it. I have tried it myself but not able to reach to a solution. I'd be glad if someone can help me out here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Could you please suggest as what is the right place on stackoverflow to ask these kind of questions?  Because I tried to include the tags which seemed relevant to me.

Comment: This doesn't belong on StackOverflow at all, since it's not a programming question. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that all trees with same number of leaf nodes have same number of internal nodes. That is shown by checking how many leaf nodes has a tree with `I` internal nodes. With `I` internal nodes, there are `2*I` edges. `I-1` of these edges connects internal nodes, so `I+1` edges are left for leaf nodes. So, tree with `n` leaf nodes, has `n-1` inner nodes.

To see that one tree can be transformed to the other tree, it is enough to transform both trees to some 'base' tree. E.g. let `A` be tree where every internal node (except last) has on left side leaf and on right side internal node. It is more like a path :-) To transformed any tree to `A` only right rotations are needed, and that is easy to find order nodes how to do rotations. To transform `T1` to `T2` it is enough to transform `T1` to `A`, and than by reverse list of rotations `A` to `T2`.

Comment: I guess, this seems good to me.  I have been thinking along the same lines. Now I think I still need to prove that A can be transformed to a left path tree by performing right rotations on all internal node that can be right rotated. It seems very intuitive but still need to find the proof.

Comment: I guess, could I do that by mathematical induction?

Comment: Yes. If leftmost leaf is on depth k, then with k-1 rightrotations it will be on depth 1, and right subtree of root is problem of size n-1 (induction step)